# Why can I set the value of an IList property with no setter with a hardcoded collection but not a variable?

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

I can write the following code and it compiles;

```
IList<ChatRequestMessage> chatRequestMessages = new List<ChatRequestMessage>();
ChatCompletionsOptions chatCompletionsOptions1 = new()
{
    Messages =
    {
        chatRequestMessages.First(),
        chatRequestMessages.Last()
    },
};
```

Obviously my chatRequestMessages are empty, but it compiles. Messages only has a setter but I can set it during construction however I can't set it like this;

```
IList<ChatRequestMessage> chatRequestMessages = new List<ChatRequestMessage>();
ChatCompletionsOptions chatCompletionsOptions1 = new()
{
    Messages = chatRequestMessages,
};
```

The above code gives me a compiler error informing me that I can't set a value with no public setter. Why is one of these allowed but not the other?

The ChatCompletionOptions can be found in the Azure.AI.OpenAI nuget package, I'm using .net 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the C# compiler has support for synthesising calls to an `Add()` method when initializing a member, which means it effectively emits this code:

```
chatCompletionsOptions1.Messages.Add(chatRequestMessages.First());
chatCompletionsOptions1.Messages.Add(chatRequestMessages.Last());
```

You can find more information about this in this documentation: [Collection initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers).

Comment: I'm sure OP knows about the collection initialier syntax, but the problem is that the syntax here is a mixture of an object initializer and collection initializer. Assigning something to `Messages` should not be allowed, but it is because you are actually not assigning something to `Messages` but modifying it. A good source for misunderstandings.

Answer (score 2):

[`ChatCompletionsOptions.Messages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.ai.openai.chatcompletionsoptions.messages?view=azure-dotnet-preview) is a readonly property:

```
public IList<ChatRequestMessage> Messages { get; }
```

So you can't assign a new value hence the compilation failure.

But C# supports addition to such initialized collection (the first snippet). See the [Object Initializers with collection read-only property initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#object-initializers-with-collection-read-only-property-initialization) section of the doc. Compiler will transform this into several `IList.Add` calls, i.e. the first snippet desugars to something like the following:

```
ChatCompletionsOptions chatCompletionsOptions1 = new();
chatCompletionsOptions1.Messages.Add(chatRequestMessages.First());
chatCompletionsOptions1.Messages.Add(chatRequestMessages.Last());
```

So basically it is not actually is initializing the collection but just adding elements to the existing one.

Comment: I guess the hard part to understand here is not that a collection initializer is syntactic sugar for `Add` calls but that the collection initializer is used at all. The syntax looks like you are initializing `ChatCompletionsOptions` with a new instance of `Messages` which you normally should not be able because it's get only. I don't like the syntax at all because of this misunderstanding.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, agree that this syntax is not very obvious. Added some expanded explanation.